# How to get an ip address in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ip-address

Hello guys I am trying to retrieve my ip address using the following c# code and all I got is the 127.0.0.0. IP address. I need to display my IPA like which would display on google searh when I type what is my ip address.
Can you help? Thank you so much

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")
Request.UserHostAddress()
Request.UserHostName()


string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(); 
string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
```

I've tried this as well but it throw an exception "only ipv4 is supported"

Comment: Try Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"), are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Also, if you're testing on your local machine, the loopback address *would* be what you get.

Comment: Thanks GalactixCowboy you are right I deploy it on my web hosting and it work fine. You are the real clint eastwood

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below:

```
using System;
```

using System.Web;

```
namespace WebApplication1
```

{

```
 public class Global : HttpApplication
{
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get request.
    HttpRequest request = base.Request;

    // Get UserHostAddress property.
    string address = request.UserHostAddress;

    // Write to response.
    base.Response.Write(address);

    // Done.
    base.CompleteRequest();
}
}
```

}